# Unknown function error with Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I am attempting to create a script in google sheets that will find competitors / similar companies of any company using Google Programmable Search Engine and G2 (G2 is a website that finds competitors. this is where the data pulls from). I followed all the steps but getting the below error. Here is where I found this approach. I know folks here are against links so feel free to ignore this and I will replicate steps below: [link](https://www.datadrivenvc.io/p/find-competitors-of-any-company-and).
Thank you in advance!!

**Steps I Took:
**

1. Opened a new google sheet
2. Went to app script and typed out the below script (substituting my API key where it says replace)
   3.Renamed project to “Similar Companies G2”
3. In google sheet I tried using the "=SimilarCompanyG2(A2) and got the below error. A2 is simply where I added a company name (let's say Google for instance).

**Error I got:
**Cell shows #NAME
Unknown function: 'SimilarCompanyG2'.

```
/**
 * Find similar companies via G2
 *
 * @param {string} companyName - Name of the company
 * @returns {string} Result
 * @customfunction
 */


function SimilarCompanyG2(companyName) {

if (companyName == ""){return "Error - Input is empty"}

  // Replace these with your actual API key
  const API_KEY = 'YOUR_API_KEY'
  const SEARCH_ENGINE_ID = 'e298e2926913441fc';

  // Formulate the query to find top 10 alternatives of a company on G2's website
  searchQuery = "Top 10 " + companyName + "Alternatives & Competitors site:g2.com/products"
  
  // Construct the URL for the Google Custom Search JSON API
  searchUrl = `https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=${API_KEY}&cx=${SEARCH_ENGINE_ID}&q=${encodeURIComponent(searchQuery)}`;

  // Send a GET request to the API
  response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(searchUrl, {method: 'get'});
  
  // Parse the JSON response
  data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

  // If there are any items in the response data
  if (data?.items?.length > 0) {
    competitorsList = data.items[0]?.pagemap?.listitem;
    
    // Log the competitors list
    console.log(competitorsList);
    
    // Filter competitors with a URL and a position, then map to their names
    competitors = competitorsList?.length > 0 ? competitorsList.filter(item => !!item.url && !!item.position).map(item => item.name) : "Not found";
    
    // Log the filtered competitors
    console.log(competitors);
    
    // If there are any competitors, return them as a comma-separated string, else return "Not found"
    return competitors?.length > 0 ? competitors.join(', ') : "Not found";
  } else {
    return "Not found";
  }
}
```